# How to automate one variable changing due to adding another variable

Tags: selenium, variables, automation, nightwatch

Is there anybody that has had luck when with Automating the task of checking Variables changing due to another triggered event variable. We are talking numbers here, for example: I have a drone that starts with 1 flight then I manually take a flight. How can I automate a check for this dynamic variable being + 1 or +2 etc for however many flights I take, to make sure the count is always monitored as working? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code trials please...

Comment: Can you share where these dynamic variables are appearing? Maybe you would like to share DOM so that someone can help you to write a dynamic locator to find the dynamical change value.

Comment: I'm sorry I am very new to coding so I am not even sure where to begin on this venture. <div_ngcontent class="duration" xpath="1">97</div> ==$0, the number here is dynamic and changes when someone flies a drone, you will not know how many flights someone takes (which is the other variable) until the count is updated on our dashboard. Once it is updated on the dashboard the count for the drone goes up. @QualityMatters

Comment: You will have to share your DOM here where this element is appearing. You can do it by: CTRL+SHIFT+I (in your browser) -> Click on Elements Tab->Mouse hover to that dynamic element ->Right click-> Inspect element. Copy that portion, update your question with that information, you will get the relevant help then

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.